# twitter drop down not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

here is the code that I am using but the dropdown is not being shown. My javascript ref erence is in the correct sequence. and i have also added a function for dropdown toggle.

```
<!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
</script>
    <link href="includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>
            <div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class= "container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> tech  site</a>
                <button= "navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                 <ul class= "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href= "#" class="active"> Home</a>   </li>
                        <li><a href= "#"> Login</a> </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href= "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Social Media<b class="caret"></b></a>                          
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href= "#" class="active">Facebook</a>    </li>
                        <li><a href= "#">Twitter</a>    </li>
                        <li><a href= "#"> Google+</a>   </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href= "#"> About</a> </li>
                        <li><a href= "#"> Contact</a>   </li>
                 </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

    </body>

<div>

 <div class="bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Footer section 1</h3>
                <p>Content for the first footer section.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Footer section 2</h3>
                <p>Content for the second footer section.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Footer section 3</h3>
                <p>Content for the third footer section.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Include jQuery and bootstrap JS plugins -->

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: There are some problems with your markup. You're closing some elements such as <body> twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the collapse plugin, and use include the wright versions of jquery and bootstrap. You don't have to insert any script of your own to make it works. Here is your code with the minimal modifications, just to make it works:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Navbar Collapse</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
          <div class= "container">
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> tech  site</a>
              <button class= "navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                  <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class= "icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
               <ul class= "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href= "#" class="active"> Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href= "#"> Login</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href= "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Social Media<b class="caret"></b></a>                          
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href= "#" class="active">Facebook</a></li>
                      <li><a href= "#">Twitter</a></li>
                      <li><a href= "#"> Google+</a></li>

                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href= "#"> About</a></li>
                      <li><a href= "#"> Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
    <div>


    <div class="bottom">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Footer section 1</h3>
                  <p>Content for the first footer section.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Footer section 2</h3>
                  <p>Content for the second footer section.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Footer section 3</h3>
                  <p>Content for the third footer section.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/m88w4j7d/1/) to see a working example.
It's better if you change the tag of the `navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top` from `div` to `nav`. And also add the `role="navigation"` to every navbar to help with accessibility.

Hope it's useful!